# Trying to build my react native app with eas build command, but ends with 403 error

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

When I build my react native app with eas build I counter this situation
.. Uploading to EAS Build (1.8 MB / 1.8 MB)
Error: Request failed: 403
And the building is rejected.
What is going on here and what should I do

I tried to log out and log in again, tried to use vpn also, deleted the project and created another one, but nothing has helped me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.